# Capturing the contents of a Listview row as variables

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, variables

`C#` `WPF`
I have a list view with 3 columns in it.  What I want to happen is when I double click on a row, it will capture the values of the columns for the selected row and store them as variables so I can pass them off to another page or simply manipulate them as needed.  What I have here is my practice code.  For right now, I am just populating a message box to see if I can get the variables out correctly.  What is happening is it is not grabbing anything from the row.  I figured this out by removing the `if` block and saw that `string name = selectedObject.ilName;` was null. an additional question I have is in regards to the statement `ingListLV.SelectedItems[0] as InventoryList` the [0], what exactly does that refer to? I initally thought it referred to the values it returned, so [0] would be the value in column 1, [1] would be column 2 etc. but i know that is wrong.

Here is my `XAML`

```
<ListView x:Name="ingListLV" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,145,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
              SelectedValuePath="InventoryName"
              Style="{DynamicResource listViewStyle}" 
              MouseDoubleClick="Open_Edit">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="InvName" Width="100" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=InventoryName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Qty" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Qty}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Type}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

and my code behind

```
    private void Open_Edit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    var selectedObject = ingListLV.SelectedItems[0] as InventoryList;
    if (selectedObject == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    string name = selectedObject.ilName;
    MessageBox.Show(name);
    }

public class InventoryList
{
    public string ilName { get; set; }
    public decimal ilQty { get; set; }
    public string ilType { get; set; }
}
```

*EDIT*
Here is where i am loading data in to the listview

```
    private void LoadLV()
    {

        auroraDataEntities = new AuroraDataEntities();
        ObjectQuery<Inventory> inventories = auroraDataEntities.Inventories;
        //Returns only opjects with a quantity greater than 0, so it won't show anything you are out of
        var fillList = from q in inventories
                       where q.Qty > 0
                       select q;
        ingListLV.ItemsSource = fillList.ToList();
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`ListView.SelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode.aspx) `Single` (which is default) use [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) not [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems.aspx).

```
var selectedObject = ingListLV.SelectedItem as Inventory;
```

The `[0]` refers to the first selected item (row) in a multiple selection.

Comment: so in my xaml i set `SelectionMode="Single"`.  And made the change you selected in the code above.  It was still populated as null.  As I was stepping through the code, I noticed that `iList` wasnt being populated with anything, so it looks like it is still having issues getting the value out of the listview.

Comment: What is iList? I hope this is the list in DataContext because your ItemsSource is bound to the object in DataContext. Do you see rows in ListView? If that can you select an item/a row?

Comment: `iList` is declared in the class `InventoryList`. Yes i can see rows in the ListView, yes I can double click in the listview and launch the `open_edit` method, but it is not pulling a value from the listview

Comment: In the class InventoryList you've posted I don't see an iList. And please show the code where you set the DataContext especially what type the object is.

Comment: Sorry, meant ilName, not ilLIst.  everything is starting to look the same lol. I'll edit the post to show where I am loading data in to the listview

Comment: Then your XAML ItemsSource declaration is useless because it will be overwritten with a list of items of type Inventory. Then of course  you have to cast the SelectedItem to Inventory not InventoryList. How did you get to InventoryList?

Comment: Awesome! That worked!  I had read a post earlier about when you are pulling data from a listview, you have to cast it into a new class so it would be readable.  Thanks again for the help!!!!!!!